# I get error when I write these lines in the SQL View of Access

Tags: database, ms-access

I was studying DBMS by using a book. In the book, the instructions are done by using Access. In the SQL View of the Query, the book says that I should write these lines to use JOIN operation and create another table. Yet, when I write them in the SQL View, I get error messages. I could not figure out this problem. Is it wrong that I use wrong syntax or something else that I don't know? Following code which is written in the book demonstrates the operation that I want to do.

```
JOIN Customer Rep
WHERE Customer.RepNum = Rep.RepNum
GIVIN Temp
PROJECT Temp Over(CustomerNum,CustomerName,RepNum,LastName)
GIVING Answer
```

Comment: I've never seen keywords `GIVIN` or `GIVING` in MS Access. Why read a book when you can just look it up? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/select-into-statement-microsoft-access-sql

Comment: Please post your error and confirm that you are putting this into MS-Access

Comment: Actually I've just started studying it. Thus I didn't have enough source knowledge to check out. I will be following this website but I still wonder if there is no such a thing like this, why would someone put these ones in a book :D

Comment: Is the book specifically about Microsoft Access? What's the book / author? There are many flavours of SQL and they don't all work together

Comment: Concepts of DBMS Phil Pratt, Mary Last. The book is not specifically about MS-Access. It just uses it to demonstrate the steps.

Comment: Well... that doesn't look like MS Access syntax to me.

Comment: Only the second line is valid Access SQL. So, either use the database the author did use, or use a book on Access SQL.

Comment: Not finding GIVEN, GIVING, PROJECT as keywords for any flavor of SQL. w3Schools doesn't list them. Would have to see book's instructions. Do you really want to create another table or just retrieve data in a query?